# vscode doesn't show inner errors when block is collapsed

Tags: visual-studio-code

suppose a function has a syntax error in one of its inner lines of code
the red line indicator is drawn for this line only.

when I collapse the function's block - the red line indicating the error is no longer visible (there is a red dot in the minimap but finding the errornous functionis not trivial from the inimap).

I would expect the red line to be denoted under the function bloch when the block is folded. is there anyway to set this up?